# DNF|YUM - Diable a package upgrade for one specific package version

Tags: package-management, yum, dnf

I'm encountering a problem on a Linux host where upgrading software package X causes package Y to stop working, and where package Y is essential for the users of that Linux host.

This Linux host uses DNF|YUM as the package manager.

I know it's possible to **permanently** prevent software updates for a given package by editing the system's YUM config files, or via a 'versionlock' app, etc.; but that's not what I want to do.

What I'm hoping to do is configure this Linux host so that it will not upgrade one specific version of package X, but it will install any newer upgrade versions of package X under the assumption that X, or Y, or both will be "fixed" in a future release.

Does DNF|YUM have the ability to block/exclude one specific version of package X when upgrading a system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `yum` or `dnf`, there is no tool that can block updates to a specific version while allowing anything afterwards. All that can be done is to use one of the methods that you've mentioned such as using versionlock or excluding it in `/etc/yum.conf` or `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` or adding an exclude line in the repo file or using `yum -x package update` when updating all packages on the system.

The best that you can do is to set up a test virtual machine where you can exclude the package using one of the methods, take a snapshot, and then test future releases to see if the breaking no longer occurs for the other package. If this package isn't a dependency for the one that is breaking, then it might be possible to compile the breaking package from source and have the it use that instead. If it is, then the test machine is your best option along with putting in a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Nasir.  I dug through the DNF|YUM documentation before posting, but I didn't find any features that would do what I wanted; so, I thought I'd ask here in case I'd missed something.  Re: "The best thing you can do is..."  That's exactly what I'm doing.  Unfortunately, package X is 'glibc', package Y is a proprietary (Cisco) VPN client, and my employer (who provides the VPN client) doesn't support the particular Linux OS I'm using.  So for the moment, I'm stuck with this annoyance.

Comment: @JimFischer If that's the case, then there's nothing that you can do although it does seem odd that a VPN client would break `glibc`. If there is conflict, which is most likely, then the VPN client just wouldn't work. Mark this question as resolved by accepting my answer and then ask a new question regarding what's happening with the VPN client and `glibc`. Include the OS that you are using and the package name for the client.